# SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment) da error de EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift2, swift

Estoy haciendo un juego con `SpriteKit` y trabajo con `SKScene` para distintas escenas dentro del juego.

Hice una clase para hacer compras `in-App` funciona bien con un botón, pero da errores con otros, me explico:

En la portada hay un botón que al presionarlo se ejecuta la ventana de comprar sin problemas todas las veces que quiero, pero si me cambio a otra escena y tengo otro botón comprar asociado la misma clase de comprar, si lo presiono da error y se cae a aplicación.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema?

Este es mi clase para comprar:

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class BuyApp: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver{

    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()
    let idEnableActividades = "id.prod.unico"
    let buy = Buy() //Base de datos con compras

    override init() {

        super.init()

        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            print("IAP is enabled, loading")
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: self.idEnableActividades)
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()

        } else {
            print("please enable IAPS")
        }

    }

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {

        let myProduct = response.products

        for product in myProduct {
            /*
            print(product.productIdentifier)
            print(product.localizedTitle)
            print(product.localizedDescription)
            print(product.price)
            print(product.priceLocale)
            */
            list.append(product)
        }

    }


    func buyCompleteVersion() {
        print("comprar versión completa")
        buy.showPurshases()
        if list.count > 0 {
            for product in list {
                print(product)
                let prodID = product.productIdentifier

                if(prodID == self.idEnableActividades) {
                    p = product
                    buyProduct()
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else{
            print("else de buyCompleteVersion")
        }
    }

    func saveBuy() {
        print("Guardando compra en DB.....")
        buy.savePurchase()
    }

    func buyProduct() {
        print("comprando " + p.productIdentifier)
        let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)

    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("transactions restored")
    }



    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

        print("add paymnet")
        if transactions.count > 0 {
            for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
                if let trans = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {

                    print("error: \(trans.error)")

                    switch trans.transactionState {

                    case .Purchased:

                        print(" productIdentifier: \(p.productIdentifier)")

                        let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String

                        switch prodID {
                            case self.idEnableActividades:
                                saveBuy()
                            default:
                                print("IAP not setup")
                        }

                        queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                        break;
                    case .Failed:
                        print("buy error")
                        queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                        break;
                    default:

                        print("default")
                        break;

                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }

    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
    {
        print("finish trans")
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
    }
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
    {
        if transactions.count > 0 {
            for transaction in transactions {
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
                print("removieno")
            }
        } else{
            print("removieno 0")
        }

        print("remove trans");
    }

    func request(request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("“Print the NSError \(error)")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice lo siguiente y me ha funcionado el mismo código.

- Hice una nueva escena para `Comprar` donde esta el botón.
- La clase `BuyApp` la deje con el patrón singleton, por lo tanto al iniciar la app cargo mis productos y no a cada rato que llamo la clase.
- En la clase `Comprar` puedo adquirir el desbloqueo y ya no hay problemas, además le deje una animación que dice "cargando" para que el usuario no presionen el botón a cada momento.